# tmux disable confirmation prompt on kill-window

Tags: tmux

I've looked through the man pages so this might be asking in vain. I get annoyed at the confirmation message for kill-window (`Ctrl-b &` or `Ctrl-b kill-window` on the default setup). This always gives:

> Confirm 'kill-window'? (y/n)

Personally, I would essentially never hit `Ctrl-b &` unintentionally. Is there any way to disable this prompt, or prompts in general in tmux?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

By default `<Prefix> &` is bound to `confirm-before -p "kill-window #W? (y/n)" kill-window`. The use of `confirm-before` causes the prompting. If you do not want the confirmation prompt, then just rebind `&` directly to `kill-window`:

```
bind-key & kill-window
```

You may also want to rebind `x`, too.  It defaults to a confirming version of `kill-pane`; though you might want to consider whether this one might be too easy to accidentally type before removing the confirmation.

```
bind-key x kill-pane
```

Note: Both examples above are suitable for direct inclusion in `.tmux.conf`, but you could also type them into a `<Prefix> :` prompt, or type them into a shell after `tmux` (though you would have to quote/escape `&` since it usually special to the shell).

I think those are the only default bindings that use `confirm-before`. You can check your particular configuration like this:

```
tmux list-keys | grep confirm-before
```

Comment: ... hallelujah!

Comment: `bind-key X kill-pane`