# TMUX: confirm-before option for kill-session command

Tags: tmux

For TMUX, we know there is a confirm-before option for kill-window. For example, posts

[How to add tmux confirm prompt when I kill a window?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96123/how-to-add-tmux-confirm-prompt-when-i-kill-a-window)
[tmux disable confirmation prompt on kill-window](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30270/tmux-disable-confirmation-prompt-on-kill-window)

Wonder if there is confirm-before option for kill-session command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> we know there is a `confirm-before` option for `kill-window`.

No, `confirm-before` is not an option for `kill-window`. It's a tmux command *like* `kill-window`. The difference is `confirm-before` upon confirmation executes another command (e.g. `kill-window`):

> ```
> confirm-before [-b] [-p prompt] [-t target-client] command
> ```
>
> (alias: `confirm`)
> Ask for confirmation before executing `command`. […]

<sup>([source](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#confirm-before))</sup>

[There is this default binding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30283/108618) that runs `confirm-before -p "kill-window #W? (y/n)" kill-window` and *maybe* this is why you thought `confirm-before` was specific to `kill-window`. Well, it's not specific.

The other command (i.e. `command`) may be `kill-session` as well. To see for yourself, type the following in the tmux prompt (note: the default key binding to open the prompt is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>,<kbd>:</kbd>):

```
confirm-before kill-session
```

and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Or invoke this in a shell running inside tmux:

```
tmux confirm-before kill-session
```

The other command may be `confirm-before`. You can do this (again shell code):

```
tmux confirm-before -p 'kill?' 'confirm-before -p "sure?" "confirm-before -p \"really?\" kill-session"'
```

where `confirm-before` runs `confirm-before` that runs `confirm-before` that runs `kill-session`.